# iOS 7 Background Audio

Tags: xcode, audio, background, ios7, midi

I'm trying to play audio in background on iOS 7. While everything worked nicely in iOS 6 it stopped to work now. If I put my app into background my audio keeps playing but as soon as I start another Audio-app like a synth app, my app can't do anything any longer (no audio / timers stopped etc.)

I'm using this code to set the audio session:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

What can I do to be still able to play audio / send midi events even if another music/audio app is in the foreground?

For playing audio effects I use FMOD.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error: nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers I think does what you want, although it's not entirely clear. Let me know if that works!